# Git overwrite master and keep history

Tags: git

I would like to overwrite the master branch and keep the history of the files.

I have an API that I generate code. Everytime I generate the code for the API, I would like to overwrite the master branch, and remove any files that I do not have locally from the remote master branch. The files that I do have locally, I would like to track their history once I push them.

I used `git push --set-upstream origin master -f` and this deleted the history of all files.

Comment: I think that I am confused by your intentions. From what I am understanding you have a git repo that an application (api) is committing to locally and you want to push those changes to the repo without loosing history, is this correct? If so, wouldn't it make more sense to have the api pull down any changes that are in master before beginning, make the changes, and then push to master? Then you only have to worry about conflicts.

Comment: Yes, I was pulling before. The problem I had was the files that were deleted locally (no longer generated) remained on the remove branch.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you are including the deletions in your commit. The copy within the actual origin should then no longer have the file. I have had cases where somebody else would delete say a .net project form the repository and the local folder would stay because I had ignored files within the bin directory that I had to delete manually, could this be the issue you are running into? If so I would assume that there is a way to tell git to completely erase the local copy and bring down the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not include any deletes in my commit, since the files I am commiting are generated

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding the way git tracks stuff. git does **not** track files... separately say. It tracks revisions (chains them, say) and the revisions themselves are the ones that have files and content (through a tree object)... so it's not like some files will have a history some way and others will have it another way.

Comment: Following from your comment here: if you want to have them deleted on the remote, you need to delete them from the revision _locally_ before you commit. That way, when you push, they will be deleted on the remote. It all comes down (again) to the way git stores stuff. Git won't push files separately. It pushes _revisions_, and they don't depend on if it's local stuff or remote stuff.

Comment: How is "overwrite the master branch" different than "make a new commit on the master branch"?

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

#### `git reset`

You can tag your current `HEAD` and once it's tagged you can revert any prior commit since git will keep the full history

---

#### `git checkout <backup branch>`

Backup the current branch history into a new branch

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range.
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit.
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# add new commit with the undoing of the original one.
# the <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

Full answer: Choose the one which suits your choice - **I added some extra info as well so you can have the full picture**

---

Before answering let's add some background, explaining what is this `HEAD`.

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch.
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time. (excluding `git worktree`)

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history its called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this- SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch

[image]

### [image]

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD - or in your case how to **keep** the history in git

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit.
This command will checkout to a given commit.
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit. 
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well.
`git reflog` will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range.
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit.
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# add new commit with the undo of the original one.
# the <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what.
As you can see there `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Comment: This is an incredibly detailed answer that somehow completely avoids answering the question that was asked.

Comment: i was to supply for an understanding of what is revert which can be used to "undo" history, reset which can be "drop" history while all of them doesn't delete the history